# Bootstrap Input File cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this [library](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Styling-Your-File-Input-with-jQuery-Inputfile-Plugin-Bootstrap.html)    to create a nice input file button with bootstrap theme.
I added a cursor pointer on the button, but 
I can not see the cursor on the whole button.

```
<button style="cursor:pointer" />
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8W9Sz/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code:

```
        $fileButton.on('click', function(){
            $(this).next('input').trigger('click');
        });
```

After:

```
$fileButton = $('<button style="cursor:pointer" class="' + config.uploadButtonClass + '">' + config.uploadText + '</button>').insertBefore($self);
```

And add styles to:

```
.inputfile .btn{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with different way using **Javascript**

You can hide the input by placing it into a div which is height:0px and overwflow:hidden. THen you add a button or an other html element which you can style as you want. In the onclick event you get the input field using javascript or jQuery and click it:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden">
   <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="fileInput" />
</div>
<button style="cursor:pointer" onclick="chooseFile();" class="btn btn-defualt"><span style="cursor:pointer" class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Search for a file to add</button>
```

Now the input is hidden, but you can style the button as you want, it will always open the file input on click.

**javascript:**

```
function chooseFile() {
      document.getElementById("fileInput").click();
   }
```

Here is <kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/26Bs7/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it properly, your problem was in inability to style shadow-dom input tag, generated by browser
This css helped me in the same issue:

```
  input[type="button"]::-webkit-file-upload-button,
  input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button,
  button::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```